# ng-click not working with uib-datepicker-popup

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, uidatepicker

I use `uib-datepicker-popup`. Nothing heppens when I click on the input field or the calendar image on this code:

```
<div>
        <label for="startDate">Start</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text"
                id="startDate"
                uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy"
                datepicker-mode="'month'"
                datepicker-template-url="project/datepicker/datepicker.html"
                datepicker-popup-template-url="project/datepicker/popup.html"
                show-button-bar="false" 
                show-weeks="false"
                is-open="startDate.opened"
                on-open-focus="true" 
                datepicker-append-to-body="true" 
                name="dateFrom" 
                min-date="minStartDate"
                placeholder=""
                ng-model="startDate"
                uib-datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd"
            />
            <span>
                <button type="button" ng-click="startDate.opened = !startDate.opened;">
                    <i aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Do you have any idea of the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: use `(tap)="method()"` or `(click)="method()"`

Comment: Please, provide plunker. From the code you provided, everything seems ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but if refer to documentation:

***ng-model*** $  - The date object. Must be a Javascript Date object. You may use the 
  uibDateParser service to assist in string-to-object conversion. (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

In your case it is not a Date

Try to create other property for holding is-open (e.g. $scope.isOpen) state:

```
<div>
    <label for="startDate">Start</label>
    <div>
        <input type="text"
            id="startDate"
            uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy"
            datepicker-mode="'month'"
            datepicker-template-url="project/datepicker/datepicker.html"
            datepicker-popup-template-url="project/datepicker/popup.html"
            show-button-bar="false" 
            show-weeks="false"
            is-open="isOpen"
            on-open-focus="true" 
            datepicker-append-to-body="true" 
            name="dateFrom" 
            min-date="minStartDate"
            placeholder=""
            ng-model="startDate"
            uib-datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd"
        />
        <span>
            <button type="button" ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen">
                <i aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Using a `Date` object in my `ng-model` solved the problem, thanks!